# Auto-Vectorization of Matrix Addition

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, vectorization, auto-vectorization

I am trying simple matrix addition code to get auto vectorized.

```
float A[100];
float A[100];
float C[100];

int n = 6;

  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        C[i*n+j] = A[i*n+j] + B[i*n+j];
```

I am getting following remarks after using Rpass analysis flag for the above code :

```
the cost-model indicates that vectorization is not beneficial [-Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize]

the cost-model indicates that interleaving is not beneficial [-Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize]

loop not vectorized: the optimizer was unable to perform the requested transformation; the 
transformation might be disabled or specified as part of an unsupported transformation ordering
```

what changes should I do to make it vectorized and what does this remarks mean ?

Comment: What is your compile options, target CPU etc ? This loop can be vectorized without any issues x86-64  https://godbolt.org/z/d8eqnv, arm-8 https://godbolt.org/z/c37WP9

Comment: Have you tried eliminating the double indexing, ie for( k=0; k<n*n; ++k) { C[k] = A[k] + B[k]; } ?